# Simple mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to give all pages on a site the option of being accessed directly or within a fake "directory"  e.g.

example.com/about.php

and

example.com/directory/about.php

should both simply access about.php.  I also want to have access to the directory's name in PHP, i.e. pass it as a GET variable (actual URL of example.com/directory/about.php would be example.com/about.php?dirname=directory).  This needs to work not just on about.php, but on any page you could access (contact.php, services.php and the like).

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Google could probably give you some strong leads.

Comment: My best lead from searching was to modify this: RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]*)$ index.php?link_id=page-$1, but I wasn't sure how to make this "dynamic" so to speak--work on all different pages.

Comment: For the record, this was certainly a real question to me; thanks to Jon Lin for answering, got me on the right path, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.php$ /$2.php?dirname=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin. Minus the backslash before .php this worked perfectly.